# Destination Host Unreachable, Centos 7, Vmware

Tags: networking, centos7, ping, vmware-server

After setting the *static IP* address on vmware machine, restarted centos, here is that after I get this error:

```
Destination Host Unreachable
```

1. I try to change NAT to Bridge but nothing change, indeed, I can not connect using Putty in *Bridge* mode via terminal
2. `nano ifcfg-ens33`

   ```
   TYPE=Ethernet
   BOOTPROTO=static
   IPADDR=192.168.52.128
   BROADCAST=192.168.52.255
   NETMASK=255.255.255.0
   GATEWAY=192.168.160.1
   DEFROUTE=yes
   PEERDNS=yes
   PEERROUTES=yes
   IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
   IPV6INIT=yes
   IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
   IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
   IPV6_PEERDNS=yes
   IPV6_PEERROUTES=yes
   IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
   NAME=ens33
   UUID=(long)
   DEVICE=ens33
   ONBOOT=yes
   DNS1=8.8.8.8
   DNS2=8.8.4.4`
   ```
3. `/etc/resolv.conf`

   ```
   #Generated by NetworkManager
   nameserver 8.8.8.8
   nameserver 8.8.4.4`
   ```
4. `lspci | egrep -i --color 'network|ethernet'`

   ```
   02:01.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82545EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller (Copper) (rev 01)
   ```
5. I am able to ping myself.
   `ping 127.0.0.1` return packets
6. `route`

   ```
   [root@localhost ~]# route
   Kernel IP routing table
   Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
   default         gateway         0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 ens33
   192.168.52.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 ens33
   gateway         0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    100    0        0 ens33
   ```
7. `ifconfig -a`

   ```
   [root@localhost ~]# ifconfig -a
   ens33: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
           inet 192.168.52.128  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.52.255
           inet6 fe80::20c:29ff:fea1:d692  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
           ether 00:0c:29:a1:d6:92  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
           RX packets 81  bytes 8444 (8.2 KiB)
           RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
           TX packets 129  bytes 15447 (15.0 KiB)
           TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

   lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
           inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
           inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
           loop  txqueuelen 1  (Local Loopback)
           RX packets 126  bytes 11662 (11.3 KiB)
           RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
           TX packets 126  bytes 11662 (11.3 KiB)
           TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
   ```
8. Network is active

   ```
   [root@localhost ~]# systemctl status NetworkManager
    NetworkManager.service - Network Manager
      Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
      Active: active (running) since sab 2017-06-10 14:29:39 CEST; 3min 36s ago
        Docs: man:NetworkManager(8)
    Main PID: 658 (NetworkManager)
      CGroup: /system.slice/NetworkManager.service
              └─658 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

   giu 10 14:29:41 localhost.localdomain NetworkManager[658]: <info>  [149709778...
   ```

I need to have a static IP because I set up a server game

Answer (score 2):

Your configured gateway is outside of your subnet.

```
IPADDR=192.168.52.128
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
GATEWAY=192.168.160.1
```

You can reach addresses within the range *192.168.52.1..192.168.52.254* without a router/gateway.
If you want to reach addresses outside this range, you need a router/gateway. That router/gateway has to be in the reachable IP address range.

Comment: mm..what IP should be insert to allow ping 8.8.8.8 works with packet returns ? Netmask of physical gateway is also 255.255.128.0

Answer (score 0):

Setting a static IP on CentOS
To find the **correct gateway**, do:

```
nmtui
// select your ens18 or eth01 or your connection-name
Modify > IPV4 > select <Automatic>
```

Go to a terminal and type

```
ip route
// you'll get
// default via 172.16.0.22 <-- this is your gateway
```

To find the **DNS server**, do:

```
nslookup google.com
// you'll
// Server: 172.18.4.13 <-- this is your DNS
```

Now you can configure you static IP as follow:

```
nmtui > Modify connection
// select connection-name > Modify
select IPV4 Configuartion > Manual
// Addresses: enter your static IP address / 24; ex. 172.16.40.4/24
// Gateway: enter your gateway
// DNS server: enter your DNS server
Then you can tick "Connect automatically" > Save
nmcli con down connection-name // or deactivate/reactivate connection from nmtui gui
nmcli con up connection-name
```